# Hacer que WebView muestre otra URL sin dejar la anterior cargada

Tags: java, android

Me gustaría saber si en android hay alguna manera de cargar en la `WebView` una URL distinta a la actual y que al retroceder no se volviera a la primera, ya que me figuro que ello consumirá recursos, y mi web necesita bastantes para cargar. Estoy usando el método `.loadUrl(url);` y he probado a usar `.destroy();` anter, volver a identificar la WebView con `findViewbyId`y después cargar la URL pero la página queda en blanco. También lo he intentado con `.clearHistory();` pero no ha dado resultado.

En otras preguntas similares a esta he visto que usan `.loadUrl("about:blank");`pero yo no quiero solo que la web previa no se vea, sino que no haya más webs además de la nueva.

¿Hay alguna otra manera de cambiar la URL actual por una nueva sin que la anterior permanezca?

Comment: Pon el código para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente para eliminar el historial cada vez que cargues una pagina nueva.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            view.clearHistory();
    });
}
```

Pero de todas formas, al pulsar el boton atras no se retrocede en el historial del webview, a no ser que sobreescribas alguno de los métodos `onKeyDown()` o `onBackPressed()`.

La página anterior tampoco se queda cargada, sino que lo que haces cuando navegas hacia atras en el historial es volver a cargarla.